# how to increase height of the image from down to top

Tags: javascript, css

here is my code for filling the tank

```
const filler=(props)=>(
    <div className={Classes.filler} style={{height: `${props.percentage}%`}}></div>
);
```

here is the css code for my filler

```
.filler{
    background: url('../../../../assets/image/dark.png');
    background-size: 180%;
    transition: height 1s ease;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    transform-origin: 0% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

the problem which i am dealing with is that instead of the image of water increasing from down to top it increases from top to down. I tried by transforming the origin of the image but it did not worked.
Here are some images for reference.

[Here i want the image to rise from the lower border but it is increasing from top to down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbjoP.png)

Comment: Is this a React app?

Comment: @Teemu `className` and `props`, it look like it is a React app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this. I'm not sure what triggers the animation, but in this example i'll just assume its hover to a link.

```
.filler{
    background: url('../../../../assets/image/dark.png');
    background-size: 180%;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}
.animationstart:hover{
   height: 200px; /* max height */
}
```

Comment: glad I could help. :)